# how to merge duplicates of first tuple element and calculate the mean value of second tuple element

Tags: python, tuples

Given this tuple:
[('Red', 7), ('Red', 2), ('Red', 4), ('Green', 3), ('Red', 11), ('Green', 6), ('Blue', 8)]

I'de like to obtain something like this:

[('Red' , 6), ('Green' , 4.5), ('Blue' , 8)]

Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, it's Python. Tag added

Comment: The question would be much better if you showed what you tried actually doing first -- and showed the _exact_ first thing that didn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can also do it by using more-itertools.
Here is example

```py
import more_itertools
import statistics

a = [('Red', 7), ('Red', 2), ('Red', 4), ('Green', 3), ('Red', 11), ('Green', 6), ('Blue', 8)]

group = more_itertools.groupby_transform(
    sorted(a, key=lambda item: item[0]),
    lambda item: item[0],
    lambda item: item[1],
    lambda g: statistics.mean(list(g))
)
print(list(group))
```

```
[('Blue', 8), ('Green', 4.5), ('Red', 6)]
```

You can read about this function [here](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.groupby_transform)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn this into a DF and do your calculation. Can turn it back into tuples after if thats your desired format.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('Red', 7), ('Red', 2), ('Red', 4), ('Green', 3), ('Red', 11), ('Green', 6), ('Blue', 8)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Color', 'Number'])
df = df.groupby(['Color'], as_index=False).mean()
print(df)
df = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]
print(df)
```

```
   Color  Number
0   Blue     8.0
1  Green     4.5
2    Red     6.0
[('Blue', 8.0), ('Green', 4.5), ('Red', 6.0)]
```